# Media Foundation screenshot hook

Tags: windows, winapi, hook, media, ms-media-foundation

It is required to take at the right time a screenshot from the application (it can be blocked, collapsed or even in a different session). The application plays a video stream through the Media Foundation:

[image]

As I understand it is necessary to intercept `MFCreateMediaSession`, what to receive `IMFMediaSession`, only here what further with this object to do? And can it be accessed from another thread?

Comment: You are unlikely to be able to take a screenshot from collapsed application. Also your hooking strategy does not seem feasible too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see that you wrote application on base of Media Foundation for playing of video -and you need take video images as a separated decoded frames. So, you have two opportunities:

1. take video frames from renderer: the regular Media Foundation renderer has `IMFVideoDisplayControl` interface - on MSDN [IMFVideoDisplayControl](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms704002(v=vs.85).aspx) - it has command `GetCurrentImage` - retrieves a copy of the current image being displayed by the video renderer - on MSDN [GetCurrentImage](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms695342(v=vs.85).aspx).
2. The second way - attach sample grabber sink to the video pipeline - Media Foundation function `MFCreateSampleGrabberSinkActivate` allows create sink from sample grabber object with [IMFSampleGrabberSinkCallback](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms697548(v=vs.85).aspx) interface - it allows get decoded video images in format of Bitmap images in System Memory. Using of sample grabber is more difficult, and I can recommend my project [Capturing Video from Web-camera on Windows 7 and 8 by using Media Foundation](https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/559437/Capturing-Video-from-Web-camera-on-Windows-and-by) for researching of the such way.

Regards.